# (Ba)sh parameter expansion not consistent in script and interactive shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I encountered the following issue with parameter expansion while trying to write a script for setting the metric of my VPN's default route.

For testing purposes, I've simplified the code to the following:

```bsh
vpn_route='default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 50'

echo ip route del "$vpn_route"
echo ip route add "${vpn_route/metric +([0-9])/metric 101}"
echo ip route add "${vpn_route/%metric */metric 101}"
```

Once I remove the echo commands, this should

1. delete the existing default route
2. Create a new route with the `metric <number>` part replaced by `metric 101`

For testing, I added a second variant with a less specific pattern.

**If I execute this code in an interactive bash shell, it works as expected:**

```bsh
$ vpn_route='default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 50'
$ echo ip route del "$vpn_route"
ip route del default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 50
$ echo ip route add "${vpn_route/metric +([0-9])/metric 101}"
ip route add default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 101
$ echo ip route add "${vpn_route/%metric */metric 101}"
ip route add default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 101
```

**However, if I execute the script, I get the following:**

```bsh
$ cat lower-vpn-priority.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

vpn_route='default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 50'

echo ip route del "$vpn_route"
echo ip route add "${vpn_route/metric +([0-9])/metric 101}"
echo ip route add "${vpn_route/%metric */metric 101}"

$ bash lower-vpn-priority.sh
ip route del default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 50
ip route add default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 50
ip route add default via 10.106.160.1 proto static metric 101
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to enable extended globs for `+([0-9])` to work. It's probably set in your `bashrc`, so is enabled in the interactive shell, but not in the script. Add `shopt -s extglob` to the script to enable it. See [Pattern Matching in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).
Without it, the pattern doesn't match, and `${var/pattern/replacement}` leaves the value as-is.

Comment: You might want to add that the reason it works at the prompt of an interactive shell is because that `shopt -s extglob` must be somewhere in `~/.bashrc` or the equivalent system-wide file in `/etc` or possibly one of the files sourced from there. For instance, I believe the third party bash-completion project enables `extglob`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yep.

Comment: Ah, that's it - I was looking for shell options/flags that might differ, but couldn't find them. Thank you!

Comment: @theCalcaholic, the command line option is `-O extglob`. The `shopt` options are nonstandard extensions, and IIRC `shopt` itself is Bash-specific. (Zsh has `setopt` for a similar purpose.) Note that you can't use `-O extglob` on the hashbang line, it won't work on Linux because it needs to be two distinct arguments.